# Persistent TCP Client in Android App doens´t receive data

Tags: android, tcpclient

I have an ESP8266 12F in Soft AP mode(Server) and trying to connect my Android App to it in persistent mode(TCP).

I'm trying with this code and I can send data but not receive the answer an I know that the answer is being sent because I'm sniffing the ESP8266 connection.

The goal is to start a TCP client connection against the ESP8266 and send packets to it depending on what button is pressed in the App and the IoT device can be busy to answer so I can't wait halting the App GUI; that's why I need a persistent connection.

I tried different approaches without success.

```
package com.coolio.tcptest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Socket myClient = new Socket();
    Boolean Connected = false;
    String serverName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);
    }

    public class client extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        String received;
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params)
        {
            //String serverName = "10.7.48.108";

            int port = 1100;
            try {
                //updateText.setText("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
               // Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
                if(!Connected)
                {
                    //myClient.addListener();

                    myClient = new Socket(serverName, port);
                    myClient.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                    //myClient.on("new message", onNewMessage);

                    Connected=true;
                }

                //updateText.setText("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                OutputStream outToServer = myClient.getOutputStream();
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

                InputStream inFromServer = myClient.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

                out.writeBytes("Connected!\r\n");

                received = in.readUTF();//Stuck here

                myClient.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {
            //Never reach here

            TextView updateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.update);
            updateText.setText("in post");
            TextView receivedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.received);
            receivedText.setText("Server says: " + received);
        }
    }

    public void onSendClicked(View view)
    {
        //EditText messageView= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
        //serverName=messageView.getText().toString();
        serverName="192.168.4.1";
        new client().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: `so I can't wait halting the App GUI; that's why I need a persistent connection.` ? All data transfer has to be done in threads. So it is not even possible to block the gui. What do you mean?

Comment: Probably your code hangs on readUTF(). Is the esp sending a utf string? You are not sending a utf string to the esp to begin with. Please show the esp code where you receive the connected string and then send the reply.

Comment: @blackapps I'm talking about the fact that the Socket doesn't have a way to add a listener "myClient.addListener();" or a way to get an event asynchronously.

Comment: `myClient.close();` If you close the client after every command you have no permanent connection.

Comment: No you did not talk about that at all. Not a word. Thats all new info.

Comment: @blackapps No, I'm not sending UTF chars I'm using ASCII but there's no ASCII method; also I'm getting a null in readUTF(). You are right, the App is hangs on that line.

Comment: @blackapps I know that if I close the client after every command I have no permanent connection, that's not my code, I just downloaded from Github and uncommented that line to get a CLOSED in the ESP8266.